# UITextView avoid collectionViewCell to be tapped

Tags: swift, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UITextView` inside a `collectionViewCell`. This `UITextView` is not scrollable, editable nor selectable. It is just there to show a few lines of data. But the collectionViewCell is clickable and it opens another page. But when I tap on the `UITextView` nothing happen. What can I do for UITextView to not avoid `collectionViewCell` to be tapped?

Comment: tried setting `textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`?

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the text view interaction with the following code:

```
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```